# Matching images to list in csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a folder with many different images (.jpg) and additionally a csv file that holds the different image names. Each row of the csv file has a different image name combination. For example, for 3 participants the combinations would look like this:

```
images1 = ['01_2.jpg', '06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg', '04_2.jpg', '10_1.jpg']
images2 = ['10_1.jpg', '01_2.jpg', '06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg', '03_1.jpg']
images3 = ['06_2.jpg', '08_1.jpg', '01_2.jpg', '04_2.jpg', '10_1.jpg']
```

In the csv file, each element from the above lists belongs in a column. Also, images1 is in row one, images2 in row two, and images3 in row 3. The file looks the following way:

[list_stim.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asUUf.png):

```
01_2.jpg, 06_2.jpg, 08_1.jpg, 04_2.jpg, 10_1.jpg
10_1.jpg, 01_2.jpg, 06_2.jpg, 08_1.jpg, 03_1.jpg
06_2.jpg, 08_1.jpg, 01_2.jpg, 04_2.jpg, 10_2.jpg
```

My problem happens when trying to select one row randomly from the csv file (going through each of its columns in consecutive order), and matching it to each name.jpg from the images folder. Since the csv file holds the order of presentation of the images in each row, I would like the name in row n column m to be matched to the image that matches its string name (e.g. '06_2.jpg').

How can I use each item from one row from the csv file to retrieve the images from a folder and present them? Until now I have done the following:

```
from psychopy import core, visual, gui, data, misc, event, logging
from time import strftime
import numpy, random
import os, glob
import string
import csv

# RETRIEVE IMAGES FROM FOLDER
path = "/Users/mdc/Dropbox/UMARM/int/stim/"
paintings = []
for file in os.listdir( path ) 
    if file.lower().endswith(".jpg"):
        paintings.append(file)

# READ ITEMS
stim_order = [] # to store some list from csv (random row)

f1 = open('list_stim.csv')
items = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

for row in items:
    stim_order.append(row)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include a sample from `list_stim.csv`

Comment: I have added a sample of how the file would look for 3 participants

Comment: It would be better to include the data in its original text format, then people can copy/paste it. As an image, you would be expecting people to type it in to test your code.

Comment: @MartinEvans I have not found a way to add the document itself but I copied the data directly under the link with the screenshot of the file.

Comment: I have included the data as you indicated.

Comment: Hope it works now? Something wrong happened before in the copy/pasting I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a random row from your CSV file, you could use the following approach:

```
import csv
import random

with open('list_stim.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    image_sets = list(csv_input)
    image_set = random.choice(image_sets)

    for image in image_set:
        print image
```

This reads the whole CSV file into a list of rows called `image_sets`. It then uses Python's `random.choice()` function to select one random row. It then uses a loop to display each image from the random row.

So a possible random output would be:

```
10_1.jpg
01_2.jpg
06_2.jpg
08_1.jpg
03_1.jpg
```

---

You could then condense this code to give you the same results:

```
import csv
import random

with open('list_stim.csv') as f_input:
    for image in random.choice(list(csv.reader(f_input))):
        print image
```